# How to crop an image in J2ME

Tags: image-processing, java-me, crop

I want to crop an image in J2ME, but I can't seem to find anything online on how to do it. I see some implementations in Java, but they use libraries not available in J2ME.

How it's done in J2ME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mutable [`Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createImage%28int,%20int%29) with the exact crop size.
Get the [`Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html) from the mutable `Image`.
Draw the original `Image` in a position that the crop area fits exactly at the mutable `Image`.

For example, if I want to crop the center of an Image:

```
Image original = Image.createImage(stream); // 320 x 240
Image crop = Image.createImage(160, 120);
Graphics cropGraphics = crop.getGraphics();
int x = crop.getWidth() / 2;
int y = crop.getHeight() / 2;
int anchor = Graphics.HCENTER | Graphics.VCENTER;

cropGraphics.drawImage(original, x, y, anchor);
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. So it's pretty much drawing an image onto another one.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about J2ME but you can always look for JQuery image crop plugins. one such tool is Jcrop. http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php